# share IKEv2 VPN connection via internet sharing (High Sierra)

Tags: network, vpn, sharing, internet-sharing

I am able to select non-IKEv2 VPN connections as network interfaces to share via "Internet Sharing", but am unable to share the IKEv2 connection.  How do I share the IKEv2 connection via internet sharing on High Sierra?

Comment: there *has* to be a way to do this via the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using pf.  Using Murus (GUI-interface to pf) static NAT, share internet via your network interface, and also share the VPN interface (mine was `ipsec0`).